# How do I get started using Java for web development?

Tags: java

OK, here's the easiest question for the day for those of you who have ever done this. I'm learning Java and I heard that Java can be used to build websites. I am coming from a PHP background, so I would really appreciate using a strongly-typed well-designed language like Java for web development. However, either I can't get my search keywords right, or there's not a single guide out there that will explain what I actually need to do to build websites in Java.

For PHP, I would need to install Apache and PHP, or a nice package like WAMP, and start putting php files in the web root.

What is Java's equivalent?

Comment: this is not an easy question in java because there are too many alternatives

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Java/Getting-Started-with-Java-Web-Development-in-Eclipse-and-Tomcat/) is a great article on using the Eclipse IDE and Apache Tomcat for building a simple web application.

Also read up on [Java Servlets](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/) and [Java Server Pages.](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/)

Hope thats enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

The Java equivalent of PHP is JSP - engines like Tomcat, Jetty, and Resin can interpret Java web applications (which can contain JSP pages), and JSPs send dynamic content to a web client the same way a PHP engine does.

But a JSP just compiles to a Java Servlet, which is a type of object that lets you directly manipulate the Request and Response objects constructed from the app container (Tomcat, Jetty, Resin).  If you put HTML directly into a JSP, equivalent Java code is generated that sends the HTML to the Response.

I think you should start by learning about Servlets and webapps - in particular, learn how a web application is organized and how it can be deployed into Tomcat.  All of this info can be found in the Tomcat manual:  here's a link to the documentation for version 5.5, I think they are up to 6 now but this is the first one google gave me and it's fine for learning on.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/index.html

Read the first four sections, as well as the sections on Servlets and JSPs.

Also, here is a pretty good Servlets tutorial:  http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

> For PHP, I would need to install Apache and PHP, or a nice package like WAMP, and start putting php files in the web root.
>   What is Java's equivalent?

You can create dynamic web pages using [**Java Server Pages**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) and [**Tomcat**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) will be used as a servlet container(+web server) in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a large language so there is a lot to learn.

If all you want to do is keep writing in PHP but running on a Java system, then consider using Quercus as that is a PHP5 implementation in Java.

See http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/ for how to get started.